# How to get a new button every 24 hours and

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm still learning SwiftUI and am in the process of creating an app.
The app basically gives 1 of 4 buttons every time it is started but what I want to do is only get a random button only every 24 hours, and it should not repeat if the app is restarted within that 24 hour period. So only 1 random button per 24 hours.
How do I assign my application to a calendar and save its data?

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var exerciseview: Bool = false
let workouts = ["Arms", "Legs", "Back", "Core"]
@State private var workout = ""

var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 10) {
        Text("Random workout for the day:")
            .bold()
            .font(.title)
        
        Button(workout) {
            exerciseview = true
        }
        .font(.largeTitle)
        .sheet(isPresented: $exerciseview) {
            switch workout {
            case "Arms": ArmExerciseView()
            case "Legs": LegExerciseView()
            case "Back": BackExerciseView()
            case "Core": CoreExerciseView()
            default:
                Text("An error has occurred.")
            }
        }
    }
    .onAppear {
        workoutGen()
    }
}

func workoutGen() {
    workout = workouts.randomElement() ?? "Error."
}}
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with the .onAppear at the end but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to save the workout. The easiest way to do this is to store it in the UserDefaults.

In workoutGen () it is now only necessary to check whether a workout has been selected within the last 24 hours.

You can do it like this:

```
func workoutGen() {
    // Is a workout saved?
    if let workout = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "workout") {
        let savedTime = UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: "workout_saved_time")
        
        // Is workout not older than 24 hours?
        if (Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - savedTime) < (24 * 60 * 60) {
            // Select old workout
            self.workout = workout
            return
        }
        
    }
    
    // Update workout
    workout = workouts.randomElement() ?? "Error."
    
    // Save workout and saved time
    UserDefaults.standard.set(workout, forKey: "workout")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate, forKey: "workout_saved_time")
}
```